# How to tag items by an array of filtering functions by the filtering functions names, smootly as I define new filtering functions

Tags: rust

I want to keep a list of filter functions and tag the items by the filters that return true. This is getting close but not quite.

```
fn adf(_bs: Bs) -> bool {
    true
}

fn bodens(_bs: Bs) -> bool {
    false
}


#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Bs;

struct MyTagger;

impl MyTagger {
    fn from_tree(&self, tree: Vec<Bs>) -> Vec<String> {

      let mut fns: Vec<&dyn Fn(Bs) -> bool>  = Vec::new();
      fns.push(&adf);
      fns.push(&bodens);

      let mut res = Vec::new();
      for path in tree {
        for adf in fns.iter() {
          if adf(path) {
            res.push(std::stringify!(adf).to_string());
          }
        }
      }
      res
    }
}
```

The main problem is std::stringify! always returns "adf" possibly the variable name i declared as adf.

The second problem is, I need to manually manage the list as I define new filtering functions, basically push them into `fns` array, and increase the static array's length.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da74c6e3d59c297d6ea7e72528edcc3f

Comment: Is the list of filtering functions constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first problem, you don't have to stringify anything, you can just store everything as `fn(Bs) -> bool` (static function pointers). You can store those in collections and check them for equality.

For the second issue, maybe you could define the predicates as anonymous functions in a static slice and identify them by their index:

```rust
static PREDICATES: &[fn(Bs) -> bool] = &[
    |_| true,
    |_| true,
    |_| true,
];
```

If you still need a good identification could always associate a name somewhat directly:

```rust
static PREDICATES: &[(&str, fn(Bs) -> bool)] = &[
    ("foo", |_| true),
    ("bar", |_| true),
    ("baz", |_| true),
];
```

or maintain a second separate slice of names.

Either way in those cases you might want to store the index of the predicate function(s) rather than the function pointers, as that makes retrieving the name easier (also depending on context / name you could just identify the predicate by their index).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with one of [Masklinn's approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77075518/442760), but if you want to generate the string based on the function names you can do so, too, using a macro (where `stringify` works similar to what you probably expected):

```rust
    pub fn from_tree(&self, tree: Vec<Bs>) -> Vec<&'static str> {
        macro_rules! doit {
            ($($adf:expr),* $(,)?) => {{
                let mut res = Vec::new();
                for path in tree {
                    $(
                        if $adf(path) {
                            res.push(stringify!($adf));
                        }
                    )*
                }
                res
            }}
        }
        doit!(
            adf,
            bodens,
        )
    }
```

If the list of predicates becomes long or frequently changes you can also generate the `PREDICATES` with a macro to avoid repeating the function names:

```rust
macro_rules! predicates {
    ($($pred:expr),* $(,)?) => {{
        [
            $((stringify!($pred), $pred)),*
        ]
    }}
}
static PREDICATES: &[(&str, fn(Bs) -> bool)] = &predicates![
    foo,
    bar,
    baz,
];
```